# simple php function

Tags: php

I wanna be able to get everything from a signed in user. Like, username, email, msn, and alto more with a function like:

```
echo getUserInfo('email');
```

gets the content of "email". but it does not work, see below:

My function:

```
function getUserInfo($field) {

global $userID;

    $sql = mysql_query("select * from users where id = $userID");
    mysql_result($sql, 0, "$field");

   return $field;

}
```

Does not work, it outputs whatever i put in the function when i call it

Comment: At this point you might just want to delete the question. Or wait 2 days and accept your own answer. Doesn't matter which, since it isn't really a descriptive question that would be searched.

Answer (score 1):

edit fixed it:

$userID = 1;

```
function getUserInfo($field) {

global $userID;

    $sql = mysql_query("select * from users where id = $userID");
    $pop = mysql_result($sql, 0, "$field");

   return $pop;

}
```

Comment: you could just `select $field from users ...`

Comment: This is to discourage people from asking and then immediately answering, and to give others a fair chance at answering the question.

Comment: note: you should probably define the function as `getUserInfo($userID,$field)` to avoid the global variable.

Comment: I think you should go search Global Variables on StackOVerflow and look at the overwhelming number of places people advocate their evilness.

Comment: By the way, this is a very bad practice imho. To get one field you select all the data, at least you can do "select $field...".
Still it is bad, because everytime you need something you send a request to db, instead of taking all at one time and using whereever you want.
Say you have a user page, where you want to output some user data, you can just use getUser($userId) { return $user; } // selects all user and return it as an object or array. Then you can use it whereever you want. This is good for db.

Comment: Huh? None of these suggestions would prevent you from using it all over the site.

Comment: Could you post an example marvin?